# How to specify typecllass function type to operate on RoseTree nodes?

Tags: haskell

I have following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}

module Main where

data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a]}
                   deriving (Show, Functor)

type IntRoseTree = RoseTree Int
type IntList = [Int]

data Node = Node {val :: Int, flag :: Bool} deriving (Show)

type NodeRoseTree = RoseTree Node
type NodeList = [Node]

data DetectionType a = One | Two | FactorOf a | DivisibleBy a

class Detection a where
  is :: DetectionType a -> a -> Bool

instance Detection Int where
  is One 1 = True
  is One _ = False
  is Two 2 = True
  is Two _ = False
  is (FactorOf a) b = a `mod` b == 0
  is (DivisibleBy a) b = b `mod` a == 0

instance Detection Node where
  is One (Node val _) = is One val 
  is Two (Node val _) = is Two val
  is (FactorOf (Node val1 _)) (Node val2 _) = is (FactorOf val1) val2
  is (DivisibleBy (Node val1 _)) (Node val2 _) = is (DivisibleBy val1) val2

class Find a where
  findBiggest :: DetectionType a -> a -> Int

instance Find NodeRoseTree where
  findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node []) = if is detectionType node then val node else 0
  findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node (x:xs)) = let searchInList = findBiggest detectionType xs in 
    if is detectionType node && val node > searchInList 
       then val node
       else searchInList

instance Find NodeList where
  findBiggest _ [] = 0
  findBiggest detectionType (x:xs) = let searchInList = findBiggest detectionType xs in
    if findBiggest detectionType x > searchInList 
       then val x
       else searchInList

main :: IO ()
main = 
  let tree1 = RoseTree (Node 1 False) [ RoseTree (Node 2 True) [], RoseTree (Node 3 False) [RoseTree (Node 4 True) [] ] ] in do
    putStrLn $ show tree1
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is One) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is Two) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is $ FactorOf (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is $ DivisibleBy (Node 3 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ findBiggest (DivisibleBy (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
```

Haskell compiler does not recognize correct types for some reason. I cannot figure out why. This is the list of errors that it spits out:

```
Main.hs:41:70: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Node’ with ‘RoseTree Node’
      Expected type: NodeRoseTree
        Actual type: Node
    • In the second argument of ‘is’, namely ‘node’
      In the expression: is detectionType node
      In the expression: if is detectionType node then val node else 0
   |
41 |   findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node []) = if is detectionType node then val node else 0
   |                                                                      ^^^^

Main.hs:42:99: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[RoseTree Node]’ with ‘RoseTree Node’
      Expected type: NodeRoseTree
        Actual type: [RoseTree Node]
    • In the second argument of ‘findBiggest’, namely ‘xs’
      In the expression: findBiggest detectionType xs
      In an equation for ‘searchInList’:
          searchInList = findBiggest detectionType xs
   |
42 |   findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node (x:xs)) = let searchInList = findBiggest detectionType xs in 
   |                                                                                                   ^^

Main.hs:43:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Node’ with ‘RoseTree Node’
      Expected type: NodeRoseTree
        Actual type: Node
    • In the second argument of ‘is’, namely ‘node’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘is detectionType node’
      In the expression: is detectionType node && val node > searchInList
   |
43 |     if is detectionType node && val node > searchInList 
   |                         ^^^^

Main.hs:50:34: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Node’ with ‘[Node]’
      Expected type: NodeList
        Actual type: Node
    • In the second argument of ‘findBiggest’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘(>)’, namely
        ‘findBiggest detectionType x’
      In the expression: findBiggest detectionType x > searchInList
   |
50 |     if findBiggest detectionType x > searchInList 
   |                                  ^

Main.hs:62:65: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘RoseTree Node’ with ‘Node’
      Expected type: Node
        Actual type: NodeRoseTree
    • In the second argument of ‘findBiggest’, namely
        ‘(tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘findBiggest (DivisibleBy (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘show
           $ findBiggest (DivisibleBy (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)’
   |
62 |     putStrLn $ show $ findBiggest (DivisibleBy (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
   |                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I mean, just look at the first error:

```
Main.hs:41:70: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Node’ with ‘RoseTree Node’
      Expected type: NodeRoseTree
        Actual type: Node
    • In the second argument of ‘is’, namely ‘node’
      In the expression: is detectionType node
      In the expression: if is detectionType node then val node else 0
   |
41 |   findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node []) = if is detectionType node then val node else 0
   |                                                                      ^^^^
```

For some reason compiler thinks that `node` is of type `NodeRoseTree` when explicitly pattern matching `findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node [])`. But it cannot be because type `NodeRoseTree` has `Node`s as leafs of `RoseTree`s. For example, `Node 1 False`. Something fishy is going on here. Please point to where I am wrong or didn't specify enough types in my code.

UPD: I figured that `DetectionType a` constraints instances of `Find` class to resolve `DetectionType a` to `DetectionType NodeRoseTree` and `DetectionType NodeList` correspondingly. This is not what I want. I want somehow for `findBiggest` function type, specifically `DetectionType a` to operate on `RoseTree` node values as `a`. Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's rather rude and unconstructive comment to make

Comment: @altern genuine apologies if you thought my comment was rude. I was just remarking that it seemed arrogant yourself to assume that the compiler was in error, rather than you. And I did intend to be constructive in trying to point out the source of the problem, but I must apologise that laziness struck when I released there was a lot of code here, with custom typeclasses, that would take time for me to fully understand. Since you have simply dumped your code without explaining what you have already done to try to fix the problem, I felt disinclined to put the effort in.

Comment: @altern do you mean you wrote all that code before trying to compile it? That's a poor way to tackle anything, especially if you're new to the language. Instead, write a small piece of code and check that it compiles. That way you'll learn in easily-digestible pieces what are the "correct types" in your program, and the reasons for it. I think GHC did an admirable job of helping you find your errors -- and it's not rude to point out who's responsible for the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with you on `#haskell`, it became clear what you are trying to do. I think the `Find` class is cumbersome, and what you are trying to do can be implemented clearly with a fold.

This requires your `RoseTree` type to have a `Foldable` instance, but luckily it's easy to add this with the `DeriveFoldable` language extension:

`{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}`

*Note: You can enable the `DeriveFunctor` and `DeriveFoldable` language extensions by enabling the `DeriveTraversable` language extension, and it can make sense to derive all three at once:*

```
data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a]}
                   deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

With a `Foldable` instance for `RoseTree`, it's easy to make a function that does what you want. You can leverage the `Ord` instance of `Maybe a` (where `Nothing` is always smaller than `Just a`). With this you can use the `max` function to return the largest value:

```
findBiggest :: (Ord a, Detection a) => DetectionType a -> RoseTree a -> Maybe a
findBiggest detectType = foldr f Nothing where
  f a maybeOld = maybeNew `max` maybeOld
    where maybeNew = if is detectType a then Just a else Nothing
```

This makes it clear what the purpose of the code is and avoids needing the cumbersome `Find` class. Afterwards, you can convert the `Maybe a` to a different value if needed. The `fromMaybe` function from `Data.Maybe` is useful for this:

`fromMaybe 0 :: Maybe Int -> Int`

---

You can also generalize the type signature of `findBiggest` so that it works with any `Foldable`, as well as `RoseTree`:

```
findBiggest :: (Foldable f, Ord a, Detection a) =>
  DetectionType a -> f a -> Maybe a
findBiggest detectType = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a]}

class Find a where
  findBiggest :: DetectionType a -> a -> Int

instance Find NodeRoseTree where
  findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node []) = if is detectionType node
```

So, on the second line, `a_Find ~ NodeRoseTree`.  Which means `RoseTree node [] :: NodeRoseTree` which is the same as `RoseTree node [] :: RoseTree Node`.
We get that `a_RoseTree ~ Node` which means `node :: Node` and `[] :: [RoseTree Node]`.

I think you are getting confused because you have three (or more?) type variables using the identifier `a`.  And because you set one of them to `NodeRoseTree`, you thought one of the others is also `NodeRoseTree`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify additional parameter of typeclass `Find`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Main where

data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a]}
                   deriving (Show, Functor)

type IntRoseTree = RoseTree Int
type IntList = [Int]

data Node = Node {val :: Int, flag :: Bool} deriving (Show)

type NodeRoseTree = RoseTree Node
type NodeList = [RoseTree Node]

data DetectionType a = One | Two | FactorOf a | DivisibleBy a

class Detection a where
  is :: DetectionType a -> a -> Bool

instance Detection Int where
  is One 1 = True
  is One _ = False
  is Two 2 = True
  is Two _ = False
  is (FactorOf a) b = a `mod` b == 0
  is (DivisibleBy a) b = b `mod` a == 0

instance Detection Node where
  is One (Node val _) = is One val 
  is Two (Node val _) = is Two val
  is (FactorOf (Node val1 _)) (Node val2 _) = is (FactorOf val1) val2
  is (DivisibleBy (Node val1 _)) (Node val2 _) = is (DivisibleBy val1) val2

class Find a b where
  findBiggest :: DetectionType b -> a -> Int

instance Find NodeRoseTree Node where
  findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node []) = if is detectionType node then val node else 0
  findBiggest detectionType (RoseTree node (x:xs)) = let searchInList = findBiggest detectionType xs in 
    if is detectionType node && val node > searchInList 
       then val node
       else searchInList

instance Find NodeList Node where
  findBiggest detectionType (x@(RoseTree node _):xs) = let searchInList = findBiggest detectionType xs in
    if findBiggest detectionType x > searchInList 
       then val node
       else searchInList
  findBiggest _ [] = 0
       
main :: IO ()
main = 
  let tree1 = RoseTree (Node 1 False) [ RoseTree (Node 2 True) [], RoseTree (Node 3 False) [RoseTree (Node 4 True) [] ] ] in do
    putStrLn $ show tree1
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is One) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is Two) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is $ FactorOf (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ fmap (is $ DivisibleBy (Node 3 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
    putStrLn $ show $ findBiggest (DivisibleBy (Node 2 False)) (tree1 :: NodeRoseTree)
```